# Propagation of Covariance

Tags: statistics

I have the simple linear equation:

$\underset{n\times1}{\vec{C}}=\underset{n \times m}{\mathbf{S}} \;\underset{m \times 1}{\vec{L}}$

where $n<m$. If the elements of $\mathbf{S}$ are static then I can propagate the covariance matrix for $\vec{L}$,  $\Sigma_{\vec{L}}$ to get the covariance for $\vec{C}$ via:

$\underset{n \times n}{\Sigma_{\vec{C}}}=\underset{n \times m}{\mathbf{S}} \; \underset{m \times m}{\Sigma_{\vec{L}}} \; \underset{m \times n}{\mathbf{S}^{\top}} $

But what can I do if the elements of matrix $\mathbf{S}$ have uncertainty? In my problem I can assume that $\vec{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ are independent.

Physically  $\mathbf{S}$ represents a normalized convolution which means that the rows of $\mathbf{S}$ sum to $1$ and each row is a shifted version of the first row.  However, I would like to allow for some variation between the rows for physical reasons and random reasons. In other words if there was no randomness in the elements of $\mathbf{S}$  the rows would still be slightly different that just sifted versions of the first row.

I have tried to generalize the following expression for $X$ and $Y$ when they are independent.

$\text{Var}[X Y]=\text{Var}[X] \text{Var}[Y]+\text{Var}[X]\text{E}[Y]^2+\text{Var}[Y]\text{E}[X]^2$

into:

$\underset{n \times n}{\Sigma_{\vec{C}}}\approx \underset{n \times m}{\sigma} \; \underset{m \times m}{\Sigma_{\vec{L}}} \; \underset{m \times n}{\sigma^{\top}}+
\underset{n \times n}{\mathbb{D}[\underset{n \times m}{\sigma^{\times 2}}\; \underset{m \times 1}{\vec{L}^{\times 2}}]} 
+\underset{n \times m}{\mathbf{S}}\; \underset{m \times m}{\Sigma_{\vec{L}}} \; \underset{m \times n}{\mathbf{S}^{\top}}$

Where the operator $\mathbb{D}[\vec{A}]$ turns the vector $\vec{A}$ in to a diagonal matrix, the notation, $A^{\times 2}$ is a element wise operation where each element is squared, and the matrix $\sigma$ holds the standard deviation of the elements of $\mathbf{S}$. Obviously this method does not force my requirement that the rows of $\mathbf{S}$ sum to $1$. But to my supersize when $\mathbf{S}$ is "band diagonal"  (The quotes because $\mathbf{S}$ is not square so each row shifts more that one location from the previous row.) I get reasonable results when compared to a Monte Carlo run.

But there has to be a better way! Feel free to throw out an of my requirements if you have a solution that requires it. I'm hoping to get a reasonably good estimate so I do not have to do Monte Carlo runs.

Comment: just curious, what is the context in which you encountered this

Comment: are the elements of $S$ taken to vary independent of one another? that is ... are you assuming covariance matrix for $S$ is diagonal with all other elements zero?

Comment: what happens in the case that the covariance matrix for $S$ contains all zeros except for the very first element $S_{1,1}$

Comment: Propagating radiance through an optical system. Each row of $S$ should sum to 1 so the elements are not completely independent but in my problem the variation in the elements is small so we could assumed that they were independent and it would not be that bad.  I do not know how to think about the covariance "matrix" of an $n \times m$ matrix unless we generalize to an $n \times m \times (n m)^2$ tensor. I have been calling $\sigma$ the standard deviation matrix where each element corresponds to standard deviation of the corresponding element in $S$ and there are no cross terms.